# Mysql query shows date results a little mixed up

Tags: mysql, date, max, temperature

I'm trying to get a minimum and maximum temperature from a database for each day.
But he retrieves the date year in wrong order I get values like this:

Array ( [00-00-0000] => 22 [00-08-2013] => 22 [01-08-0201] => 24 [01-08-0213] => 24 [01-08-2013] ...

if I verify the data from the table with PHPmyAdmin everithing seems ok.

**code:**

```
$query = "SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%d-%m-%Y') as Datum1, min(`Temperatuur`)as minTemp ,max(`Temperatuur`)as maxTemp FROM `tableGreenhouse`  GROUP BY `Datum1` ORDER BY 1";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $date = $row['Datum1'];
        $Temp1 = $row['minTemp'];
        $Temp2 = $row['maxTemp'];

        $dataArray1[$date]=$Temp1;
        $dataArray2[$date]=$Temp2;  

    }

}

print_r($dataArray1);
print_r($dataArray2);
```

Comment: I wouldn't group on a custom field in this case. Grouping on `Datum` should be enough. The `ORDER BY` is also unnecessary.

Comment: thx for your reply, but that doesn't solve the problem. It stil mixed my year results. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your query.

Maybe you could try casting the variables to a certain type using the following code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // In some cases, code breaks if you do not do this...
    // Experienced it myself a few times.
    $dataArray1 = array();
    $dataArray2 = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        /* For error checking, enable following statement: */
        // var_dump($row);

        $date = (string)$row['Datum1'];
        $Temp1 = (float)$row['minTemp'];
        $Temp2 = (float)$row['maxTemp'];

        $dataArray1[$date]=$Temp1;
        $dataArray2[$date]=$Temp2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The data is send by an arduino program that puts datum, temperature, humidity, lightlevels in to my sql database. (i just emptyed the database to see of that was a case. 

your code an it give me the next result:
array(3) { ["Datum1"]=> string(10) "25-08-0013" ["mint"]=> string(2) "23" ["maxt"]=> string(2) "23" } array(3) { ["Datum1"]=> string(10) "25-08-2013" ["mint"]=> string(2) "23" ["maxt"]=> string(2) "23" } Array ( [25-08-0013] => 23 [25-08-2013] => 23 )


If you mail me  i send you the ful code with acces to the database info@xtofdesign.com

Comment: Apparently, the data in your DB is corrupted... Although you mention that if you verify the data, everything is ok. Have you also tried executing your query in phpMyAdmin directly, or have you just checked the data in your db?

Comment: Youre wright if the query runs in phpMyAdmin it makes the same error, but if you just check the data its ok. Strange maybe its because i send the date info from my arduino.

Thx a lot for helping ;)

Comment: My guess is the Arduino is putting the wrong info in the db. The field Datum is set as DateTime?